# How i can sort ip address in Rails 4 using postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sorting, ip-address

I have "ip" column in my postgresql table which contain ip addresses. I want to sort these ip addresses in ascending order. Below is data for example

```
    147.226.211.40
    1.39.80.12
    128.237.199.43
```

Result should be

```
    1.39.80.12
    128.237.199.43
    147.226.211.40
```

In other way around, so if ip address is a.b.c.d then sort by a, then by b, then by c and then d.

This below not work for me in model.

```
  default_scope { order('ip ASC') }
```

How i can do it?

Comment: An IPv4 address can actually be stored as a 32-bit integer. And I wonder what `1.39.80.,12.97` is.

Comment: It was my mistake when put question.

Comment: An IPv4 address actually *is* a 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports an inet data type. Use the right data type, and many problems just vanish.

```
scratch=# create table test (
scratch(# ip_addr inet not null);
CREATE TABLE
scratch=# insert into test values ('147.226.211.40');
INSERT 0 1
scratch=# insert into test values ('1.39.80.12');
INSERT 0 1
scratch=# insert into test values ('128.237.199.43');
INSERT 0 1
scratch=# select * from test order by ip_addr;
```

```
    ip_addr     
----------------
 1.39.80.12
 128.237.199.43
 147.226.211.40
(3 rows)
```

[ActiveRecord](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html) supports the inet data type. In brief . . .

```
$ bin/rails generate scaffold IpAddr ip_addr:inet
```

Edit the controller. Order by the symbol `:ip_addr`.

```
$ head -9 app/controllers/ip_addrs_controller.rb 
class IpAddrsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ip_addr, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /ip_addrs
  # GET /ip_addrs.json
  def index
    @ip_addrs = IpAddr.all.order(:ip_addr)
    #                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  end
```

Browse to that page, and you'll find the IP addresses ordered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast to inet for the purpose of ordering:

```
ORDER BY ip::inet ASC
```

This should work:

```
default_scope { order('ip::inet ASC') }
```

Or, in your case with bad data, this may work, though it will be terribly slow without creating an index:

```
ORDER BY regexp_replace(ip, '.?([3-9]\d{2}|25[6-9]|2[6-9]\d)', '')::cidr
```

Comment: Error is "PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type inet: "12.33.44.555" : SELECT "ip_addresses".* FROM "ip_addresses" ORDER BY ip::inet ASC"

Comment: Obviously it's not going to work if your IP addresses are invalid.

Comment: @Kashiftufail: 12.33.44.555 isn't a valid ip address, something is wrong with your input. At least you now know why you should use the best matching datatype and some input validation.

Comment: @BenGrimm: An ALTER TABLE to change the datatype for this column is a better fix. An index on this column could also speed up the query.